# c# find if whether the number is happy or not

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

Im trying to understund how do I find whether the number is Happy Number or not,
I know that i need to check if the unit digit and the digit in the highest number location are greater 
then the numbers in the middele.
`example:
given number: 63240
the unit: 6
the number in the highest location:0
are both of them greater then 3 and 2 and4(middle) ? yes
result: true (for that case)

`the quation is:
write a program that get a number from user, the program will print if the given number from the user is a happy number or not`

I know how to find the units and the highest number location, but got stack figure it out how to 
how to use the digits in the middle in order to find the answer for that..

notice that the only class we've learned so fat is Math,(not even string yes) 
we also learned while and for but nothing so far..

I also know that in order to go through all digit in given number i need to use the while loop,
but I dont know how do I use it in order to use them to get to the answer..

my code so far:

```
int number;
int units;
int highestDigitLoc; 

bool isHappyNumber = true;
int count = 0;

Console.WriteLine("enter a number:");
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while(number > 0)
{
    count++;

    units = number % 10;
    highestDigitLoc = number / 10;
}
```

thanks

Comment: I'm very confused by your description... firstly, in "63240", surely "0" is the unit and "6" is the highest (most significant) location? and last time I checked, 0 was not greater than 3, 2 or 4 - so surely the example should report `false`?

Comment: Divide by 10 first then use mod 10  (%10).

Comment: Im not sure if I understood the qeuation by myself, that is why im asking here..

Comment: Have you checked the internet was a happy number ist? Wikipedia for example

Comment: Where did you get the question from?  A link might help.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom and indeed, the wikipedia definition of [happy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the question shown :)

Comment: my teacther gave me the quation to solve, and I indeed checked the internet and the media about Happy Number and still didnt understood any of it..
Basicly the qeuation is find if given number is a happy or not

Comment: @Moshiko Can you show what teacher gave as a question or did you write it down yourself?

Comment: here is the quation:
write a program that get a number from user,
the program will print if the given number from the user is a happy number or not

Comment: @Moshiko can you edit your question to include that new information

Comment: yes I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/11/find-happy-numbers-in-c/) explains what `Happy Number`'s are in a simple way. Basically you have to keep suming the square of each digit present in the number, until the result equals 1. This proccess can go on indefinitely, but fortunately we know for certain that if the sum equals 4, it will never result in a Happy Number. Therefore, we can do the following:

```
private static bool IsHappy(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return true;
    else if (n == 0 || n == 4)
        return false;
    else
        return IsHappy(SumDigitSquares(n));
}

private static int SumDigitSquares(int n)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return n * n;
    else
        return SumDigitSquares(n % 10) + SumDigitSquares(n / 10);
}
```

Usage:

```
bool result = IsHappy(63240); //false
```

Comment: Are you sure that all non-happy numbers will be ended with 4?

Comment: How about n = 0?

Comment: @ManojBanik you are right, 0 needs to be taken into account as well

Comment: The sum of squares of all digits eventually reaches one of the 10 numbers 0, 1, 4, 16, 20, 37, 42, 58, 89, or 145. So you can improve your adding few more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question very *vague*, however, we can turn the number into an *array of digits* `int[] digits`

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] digits = null;

while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("enter a number:");

  // string : let's solve for arbitrary long numbers (no necessary int)
  string number = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number)) 
    Console.WriteLine("Empty string is not enough");
  else if (number.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
     // This code preserves leading zeroes
     digits = number.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
     // This code removes leading zeroes
     //digits = number
     //  .SkipWhile(c => c == '0')
     //  .Select(c => c - '0')
     //  .DefaultIfEmpty()
     //  .ToArray();

    break;
  } 
  else
    Console.Write("Not a valid integer value. Please, try again."); 
}
```

Then we can use this `int[] digits` to implement any *logic required*. 
Please, note, that we **preserve** *leading zeroes*:

```
"63240"  -> int[] {6, 3, 4, 2, 0}
"063240" -> int[] {0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 0}
```

e.g.

> let a number be happy if and only if
>
> 1. It contains at least **3** digits (in order to have *middle* ones)
> 2. Max of the first and last digits is greater than max of all the other digits

In our case with `63240`

1. `63240` has 5 digits, the condition holds
2. `Max(0, 6) == 6 > Max(3, 2, 4) == 4`, the condition holds

Code:

```
bool isHappyNumber =
  digits.Length >= 3 &&
  Math.Max(digits[0], digits[digits.Length - 1]) > 
    digits.Skip(1).Take(digits.Length - 2).Max();
```

**Edit:** let's implement `isHappyNumber` with good old `for loops`:

```
int maxFirstAndLast = digits[0] > digits[digits.Length - 1]
  ? digits[0]
  : digits[digits.Length - 1];

int maxMiddle = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < digits.Length - 1; ++i)
  if (digits[i] > maxMiddle) then
    maxMiddle = digits[i];

bool isHappyNumber =
  digits.Length >= 3 &&
  maxFirstAndLast > maxMiddle;
```

Comment: we're not using break yet,  the only class we use right now is .Math,
is there a wey solving it using the Math class ?

Comment: I don't think that is what a happy number is as 19 is 10-happy based on wikipedia

Comment: @Andrew: For sure it is not n-based happy numbers; actually, the question is *vague* and we even don't know the definition of happy number from it. I wanted to show the prinicple: turning the string into array of digits on which we can apply the required logics. I've tried to reconstruct / guess what happy number is in order to demonstrate how to apply the logic.

Comment: I know its possible doing it with string, but we're not there yet

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Remeber to add using System.Linq;
        public static bool IsHappyNumber(int num)
        {
            var numbers = new List<int>();
            while (true)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                var digits = num.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList();
                foreach (var digit in digits)
                    sum += digit * digit;
                
                if (numbers.Contains(sum))
                    break;

                numbers.Add(sum);
                num = sum;
            }
            return numbers.LastOrDefault() == 1;
        }
```